# HTML pages loaded in DIV / innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, load, innerhtml

i would need help on an innerHTML issue, sorry i'm not a developer :)

i have a form with two menus, a variable reads the two values selected to create the name of a HTML page and display it in a DIV with innerHTML.
so far, everything works fine.
the thing is that i want to display a message if the HTML page doesn't exist, and i can't figure out how to code *"if the DIV hasn't loaded any page (failed to load resource), then show an error message"*

here is the script, which is called when clicking on the submit button of the form :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function ShowMyPage() {
        var country_entered = document.getElementById("Country").value;
        var data_entered = document.getElementById("DataType").value;
        var mypage = "data/" + country_entered + "_" + data_entered + "/"+ country_entered + "_" + data_entered + ".html";
        var maindiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');
        maindiv.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%" data='+mypage+' ></object>';

// everything works so far, the following line doesn't

        if (maindiv.innerHTML == "") { maindiv.innerHTML = 'ERROR MESSAGE'; }       
};
</script>
```

the last line doesn't work which is logical since the DIV is not empty, but contains the link of a page that don't exist.
how to check if the HTML page has been loaded correctly and if not, display an error message ?

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a logic / design problem than it is a coding one.
The way you are going with it has a few flaws and you have just stubbled on one of them. A better and a lot more common approach in most applications would be to first **validate** user input , and that means (apart from actuall validation to avoid malicious code inputs) checking if the Page actually exists and then create (or Not) the HTML `<object>`.

There are various ways to achieve that.

Using jQuery to **load** the page and catch the error:

```
 jQuery("#maindiv").load( mypage , function( response, status, xhr ) {
   if ( status == "error" ) {
     // Do Something with the error
     console.log(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
   }
 });
```

Using jQuery and making an **AJAX** request to check if page exists:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: mypage,
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      // Do Something if the page is not found
    }
  }
});
```

There are a lot more but i am just providing a different approach , you can easily find a lot of ways to achieve this one.

Generally you need to first check if the Page exists with any way you want and then create your HTML `<object>`.

Comment: thanks for the help with that logical issue! works perfectly with the ajax method